# How do I show/hide a Wordpress post description or any other field on the front end

Tags: wordpress, field, frontend

how can I control an in individual post field to appear or not to appear on the front/end with a checkbox - hide from front end. E.g. like in this mockup - http://screencast.com/t/Q71rxUcxOrx

Is there a plugin for that or could you point me to an article?

Answer (score 0):

Create post meta of check box and with its check/uncheck you can hide/display post content at front end.

For that you have to modify code at front end for whether check box is selected or not and base on it display post content as well.

Answer (score 0):

Try below code (it's a separate plugin) - it hides whole post on Frontpage - feel free to modify it.

```
<?php
/**
 * Plugin Name: Hide post on frontend
 * Description: Allows define whether post should be displayed on frontend or not.
 * Version: 1.0.0
 * Author: Lukas Pawlik
 * License: GPL2
 */

/**
 * Adds new metabox.
 *
 * @return void Method does not return.
 */
function hpof_add_meta_box() {
    add_meta_box(
        'hpof_hide_post',
        'Hide this post on frontend',
        'hpof_add_meta_box_content',
        null,
        'side',
        'high'
    );
}

/**
 * Outputs metabox contents.
 *
 * @param WP_Post $post
 *
 * @return void Method does not return.
 */
function hpof_add_meta_box_content( WP_Post $post ) {
    $checked = (bool)get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'hpof_hide_post', true );
    echo '<input type="checkbox" name="hpof_hide_post" ' .
        ( $checked ? 'checked' : '' ) . '/> Hide this post';
}

/**
 * Handles post saving.
 *
 * @param int $post_id Post id.
 *
 * @return void Method does not return.
 */
function hpof_save_post( $post_id ) {
    $value = (int)isset( $_POST['hpof_hide_post'] );
    update_post_meta( $post_id, 'hpof_hide_post', $value );
}

/**
 * Adds custom filtering.
 *
 * @param WP_Query $query
 *
 * @return void Method does not return.
 */
function hpof_pre_get_posts( WP_Query $query ) {
    if ( is_home() ) {
        /** @var $wpdb wpdb */
        global $wpdb;
        $results = $wpdb->get_col(
            "SELECT post_id FROM {$wpdb->prefix}postmeta WHERE " .
                "meta_key = 'hpof_hide_post' AND " .
                "meta_value = 1"
        );
        $query->query_vars['post__not_in'] += $results;
    }
}

add_action( 'add_meta_boxes', 'hpof_add_meta_box' );
add_action( 'save_post', 'hpof_save_post' );
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'hpof_pre_get_posts' );
```